# Exclude a string in a regex in dreamweaver find and replace

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

i am practicing Regular expressions for Dreamweaver's find and replace function.
What i am trying to get now is to select the everything starting from "href" of the anchor tags and end at the white space after the "href".

For Example:

```
<a href="index.html" title="homepage">
```

I am using

```
href[\W\w\d\D]*?[^ ]*
```

It does one part. i.e it does search href and its value untill the space before title attribute. But how to exclude href in this search? Like it start the search after href?

Comment: Dreamweaver probably supports PCRE, try saying `href\K[\W\w\d\D]*?[^ ]*`

Comment: @devnull Nope, its not working

Comment: Does `(?<=href)[\W\w\d\D]*?[^ ]*` work?

Comment: @devnull
it won't work as we can't use quantifiers at the start of regex...

Comment: It's a positive-lookbehind.  I'm not sure if that'd work in Dreamweaver.  You might want to try it, though.

Comment: I tried it but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Better check out the following link for various types of regular expression find and replace buddy:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html